# Kotlin & Spring Boot @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

How to properly initialize ConfigurationProperties in **Spring Boot** with **Kotlin**?

*Currently* I do like in the example below:

```
 @ConfigurationProperties("app")
 class Config {
     var foo: String? = null
 }
```

But it looks pretty ugly and actually `foo` is not a `var`iable, foo is **constant** `val`ue and *should be initialized during startup and will not change in the future*.

Comment: This is fine the way it is. Spring uses JavaBean binding, so you need getters/setters. `ConfigurationProperties` is for typesafe configuration, it's not a `data` class.

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8762 which is dicussing about supporting properly immutable data classes for `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Comment: (2021) This blog post has a complete guide for using ConfigurationProperties in Kotlin: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-use-spring-boots-configurationproperties-annotation-in-kotlin-s-dataclass-1341c63110f4

I've tested it in the latest Spring Boot (2.4.1).

Basically, you need to add ConstructorBinding annotation to the data class. And add ConfigurationPropertiesScan annotation to the Application class

Answer (score 66, accepted):

With new **Spring Boot 2.2** you can do like so:

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "swagger")
data class SwaggerProp(
    val title: String, val description: String, val version: String
)
```

And don't forget to include this in your dependencies in `build.gradle.kts`:

```
dependencies {
  annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
}
```

Comment: It's my understanding that kapt has replaced annotationProcessor. You would use Kotlin 1.3.50+ and `plugins { ... kotlin("kapt") }` and `kapt(...)` to wrap the dependency string instead of `annotationProcessor(...)`

Answer (score 56):

Here is how I have it working with my application.yml file.

```
myconfig:
  my-host: ssl://example.com
  my-port: 23894
  my-user: user
  my-pass: pass
```

Here is the kotlin file:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myconfig")
class MqttProperties {
    lateinit var myHost: String
    lateinit var myPort: String
    lateinit var myUser: String
    lateinit var myPass: String    
}
```

This worked great for me.

Comment: After some research this seems like the most reasonable option. It avoids having repetition with a bit dirty @Value annotation, and will also ensure that configuration is set in properties file (if related config entry is missing, exception will be thrown that the value is not initialized).

Comment: What about primitive types, since `lateinit` is not allowed for them?

Comment: How to access these properties from other Spring `@Service` or other `@Component` classes?

Comment: @kiltek you can take the configuration bean that is created and use that bean in other components and services.

Comment: What happens if any of the late init properties here aren't present in the environment - do you get a runtime null pointer exception ?

Comment: @PaulNUK you will get an kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException if you try and access the variable without initializing it.

Answer (score 26):

**Update: As of Spring Boot 2.2.0, you can use data classes as follows:**

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("example.kotlin")
data class KotlinExampleProperties(
        val name: String,
        val description: String,
        val myService: MyService) {

    data class MyService(
            val apiToken: String,
            val uri: URI
    )
}
```

For further reference, see the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-kotlin-configuration-properties).

---

**Obsolete as of Spring Boot 2.2.0, Issue closed**

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties): A "**Java Bean**“ has to be provided in order to use `ConfigurationProperties`. This means your properties need to have getters and setters, thus `val` is not possible at the moment.

> Getters and setters are usually mandatory, since binding is via standard Java Beans property descriptors, just like in Spring MVC. There are cases where a setter may be omitted [...]

This has been resolved for Spring Boot 2.2.0, which is supposed to be released soon:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8762

Comment: Can you give an example on how the application.properties file should look like for the given code sample? I am having a similar scenario where i am not sure how to pass values to constructors with more than one parameter.

Comment: From https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/:

`example.kotlin.myService.apiToken=YourToken`
`example.kotlin.myService.uri=YourUri`

Answer (score 12):

On Spring Boot 2.4.3 with Kotlin 1.4.3 the next approach is no longer working (maybe because of a bug):

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TestProperties::class)
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConstructorBinding

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
@ConstructorBinding
data class TestProperties(
    val value: String
)
```

The code above starts working after implying one of the next two approaches:

1. Add dependency

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
```

2. Update Properties class

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConstructorBinding

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
data class TestProperties @ConstructorBinding constructor(
    val value: String
)
```

The problem happens at the line org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.java#68

Comment: Sadly ConstructorBinding doesnt work well with RefreshScope and Spring Boot devs don't want to fix this. I would advice using lateinit var instead. See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1547

Comment: @scre_www: "Spring Boot devs don't want to fix this" - it has already been closed as "won't fix"

Comment: Thanks for this, been struggling all afternoon on the bug

Answer (score 7):

```kotlin
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "your.prefix")
data class AppProperties (
    val invoiceBaseDir: String,
    val invoiceOutputFolderPdf: String,
    val staticFileFolder: String
)
```

Don't forget to add `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan`

```kotlin
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

And finally the application.properties file:

```
your.prefix.invoiceBaseDir=D:/brot-files
your.prefix.invoiceOutputFolderPdf=invoices-pdf
your.prefix.staticFileFolder=static-resources
```

Answer (score 6):

```
@Value("\${some.property.key:}")
lateinit var foo:String
```

could be used this way

Comment: Thanks, for you comment. I know about `@Value` annotation, but I do not consider this way, because it produces a lot of  boilerplate code, `@ConfigurationProperties` definitely better.

Comment: This is just a workaround. `@Value` indeed should not be used as a replacement for `@ConfigurationProperties`, since it causes boilerplate code. The way something works ought not to be a right solution.

Answer (score 6):

As of **Spring Boot 3.0** if you have a single constructor, you don't need to use `@ConstructorBinding` annotation anymore.

```kotlin
 @ConfigurationProperties("app")
 data class Config(
     val foo: String = "default foo"
 )
```

more info [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32416#issuecomment-1315070262)

Comment: Could be default value omitted ?

Comment: Note that is true only if there's only 1 constructor:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#constructingbinding-no-longer-needed-at-the-type-level

Answer (score 2):

application.properties

```
metro.metro2.url= ######
```

Metro2Config.kt

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "metro")
data class Metro2PropertyConfiguration(

        val metro2: Metro2 = Metro2()
)

data class Metro2(
    var url: String ?= null
)
```

build.gradle

```
Plugins:
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt' version '1.2.31'

// kapt dependencies required for IntelliJ auto complete of kotlin config properties class
    kapt "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
```

Comment: in version 1.3.50+, you no longer need both kapt and compile

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

application.properties

```
my.prefix.myValue=1
```

MyProperties.kt

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.prefix")
class MyProperties
{
    private var myValue = 0
    fun getMyValue(): Int {
        return myValue;
    }

    fun setMyValue(value: Int){
        myValue = value
    }
}
```

MyService.kt

```
@Component
class MyService(val myProperties: MyProperties) {
    fun doIt() {
        System.console().printf(myProperties.getMyValue().toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I also added the annotation `@EnableConfigurationProperties`, but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what's already been said, note that `val` and `@ConstructorBinding` has some limitations. You cannot alias one variable to another. Let's say you're running in Kubernetes and want to capture the hostname, which is given by the env var `HOSTNAME`. The easiest way to do this is to apply `@Value("\${HOSTNAME}:)"` to a property, but it only works for a mutable property and without constructor binding.

See [@ConstructorBinding with immutable properties don't work with @Value in Spring Boot Kotlin @ConfigurationProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66483609/839733).