# kotlin, spring boot and data classes for configuration

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, data-class

I've implemented several projects with spring boot and java. Now I'm evaluating, if I could do it with kotlin.

I am struggling with `@ConfigurationProperties` and data classes.

Simple example:

```
api:
  clientId: client123
  url: https://api.url.com
  key: api-access-key
```

Data class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("api")
@ConstructorBinding
data class ApiConfiguration(
    val clientId: String,
    val url: String,
    val key: String
)
```

Starter class:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApiConfiguration::class)
@SpringBootApplication
class SpringdemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<SpringdemoApplication>(*args)
}
```

If I'm running a test, I get the following message:

```
s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

...


Description:

ApiConfiguration is annotated with @ConstructorBinding but it is defined as a regular bean which caused dependency injection to fail.

Action:

Update your configuration so that ApiConfiguration is defined via @ConfigurationPropertiesScan or @EnableConfigurationProperties.
```

The following post doesn't help me: [Kotlin & Spring Boot @ConfigurationProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953118/kotlin-spring-boot-configurationproperties)

Environment:

- spring boot 2.7.8
- kotlin 1.6.21

Can someone help me to understand and solve the problem?

Comment: can you show us your configuration ? You should not use @Bean or Bean dsl to register ConfigurationProperties that use ConstructorBinding. You should use EnableConfigurationProperties or configuration property scanning.

Comment: @JEY I've added my starter class. I thought using ```@ConfigurationPropertiesScan``` on my starter would be enough to initialize ```ApiConfiguration``` correctly. Am I wrong?

Comment: I've got an exemple of a mini spring-boot app in kotlin with configuration properties as immutable data class. Maybe you can check configuration differences from your build and code ? -> https://github.com/alexismanin/get-started-spring-boot/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/fr/amanin/demos/hellospringboot/HelloSpringBootApplication.kt

Comment: @ThiloSchwarz yes it should. You don't have any other `@Configuration` class ?

Comment: @JEY Later I'll have a lot of ```@Configuration``` classes ...
@amanin I've try to use ```@EnableConfigurationProperties```, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I've found another strange log:
```Error creating bean with name 'apiConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}```
Looks like spring couldn't work with kotlin.String ?