# @ConfigurationProperties without default values in spring boot 3 using Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, configurationproperties

I try to implement my first **spring boot** application using **Kotlin**.
**spring-boot** version is **3.1.0**

I have a configuration class like this(based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/74445643/2674303):

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.prefix")
data class MyProperties(
    var username: String = "",
    var privateKeyPath: String = "",
```

This works fine but I don't want to see default values here because they are useless and in java you don't have to have them.

I've found following post:
[Kotlin & Spring Boot @ConfigurationProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953118/kotlin-spring-boot-configurationproperties)

And started to apply solutions from there:

1.

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.ConstructorBinding


@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.prefix")
@ConstructorBinding
data class MyProperties(
    var username: String = "",
    var privateKeyPath: String = "",
```

I get compilation error:

```
This annotation is not applicable to target 'class'
```

2. 

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.prefix")
data class MyProperties {
    lateinit varusername: String = "",
    lateinit var privateKeyPath: String = "",
```

I receive an error which points to the first fileld:

```
Property getter or setter expected
```

Have I missed something ?

Comment: I get the error during startup:
`Parameter 0 of constructor in *.*.MyProperties  required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.`

Comment: If you don't want to provide default values, Kotlin requires that the properties are either immutable (`val`) or nullable. You should not use `@Autowired` as you want properties to be bound, not beans to be injected.

Comment: @Andy Wilkinson 
Itried 2 options:

1.
`val username: String?,`
=> `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate ....  No default constructor found`

Comment: 2.
`var username: String?,`

=>`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate...No default constructor found`

Comment: @Andy Wilkinson I would appreciate if you could provide the whole example

Comment: You should not annotate your class with both `@Configuration` and `@ConfigurationProperties`. Your class is either a configuration properties pojo, or a spring configuration class. Mixing both might lead to unexpected results. If you need your properties from a configuration class, just inject the property pojo in the configuration class. You can check this kotlin configuration properties object in [an example project of mine](https://github.com/alexismanin/get-started-spring-boot/blob/main/src/main/kotlin/fr/amanin/demos/hellospringboot/HelloSpringBootApplication.kt#L95)

Comment: @amanin when I put annotation `@ConstructorBinding` over MyProperties I receive error:  "This annotation is not applicable to target 'class'"

Comment: @amanin Without ConstructorBinding your solution is working, Would ypu like to add answer ? I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.prefix")
data class MyProperties {
    lateinit varusername: String = "",
    lateinit var privateKeyPath: String = "",
 ...

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProperties ::class)
class LdapConnectionPoolConfig(
    private val myProperties : MyProperties 
) {
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research [here](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/spring-boot-configurationproperties) and [there](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) I got so use `val` for config properties like this (for Spring Boot 2.2 and later):

Config class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.prefix")
data class MyConfig @ConstructorBinding constructor(
    val config_one: String,
    val config_two: String,
}
```

Main Spring class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
class MySpringApplication
```