# How to register new collection factories in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I would like to be able to be able to inject instances of `ImmutableList` (from Guava) in my Spring Boot `@ConfigurationProperties` classes (without having to do an `ImmutableList.copyOf(...)` for each value).

I've tried adding various converters, but it looks like property binding attempts to build the collection directly, so converters like `public class ListToImmutableListConverter implements Converter<List<Any>, ImmutableList<Any>>` are never called.

Based on the stack trace, it looks like creation of the property fails in `CollectionFactory.createCollection(...)`, but I don't see any extension points for adding new collection types there. Is there a straightforward way to register new collection types with Spring?

Edit: For reference, this is a mixed Kotlin/Java environment, so we can't just rely on Kotlin's "MutableList vs List" because a Java bean can get the `List` and call `.add(...)` on it.

Code:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val context = SpringApplication.run(Microservice::class.java, *args)
    println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    context.getBean(SomeBean::class.java).doStuff()
    println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    SpringApplication.exit(context)
}

@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
class Microservice

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
@Validated
class Properties(
    val someList: ImmutableList<String>
)

@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
class ListToImmutableListConverter : Converter<List<Any>, ImmutableList<Any>> {
    override fun convert(source: List<Any>): ImmutableList<Any> = source.toImmutableList()
}

@Component
class SomeBean(
    private val properties: Properties
) {
    fun doStuff() {
        println(properties.someList)
    }
}
```

Example `application.yaml` file:

```yaml
spring.application.name: test-service
test:
  some-list:
    - foo
    - bar
    - baz
```

Other conversion methods attempted (with `TODO`, just to see if Spring would even call the converters):

```kotlin
@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
class ListToImmutableListConverter : GenericConverter {
    override fun getConvertibleTypes(): Set<GenericConverter.ConvertiblePair> = immutableSetOf(
        GenericConverter.ConvertiblePair(List::class.java, ImmutableList::class.java)
    )


    override fun convert(source: Any?, sourceType: TypeDescriptor, targetType: TypeDescriptor): Any? {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}


@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
class ListToImmutableListConverter : ConverterFactory<List<*>, ImmutableList<*>> {
    override fun <T : ImmutableList<*>?> getConverter(targetType: Class<T>): Converter<List<*>, T> {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

Example failure logs:

```
18:56:05.069 [main] WARN  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'someBean' defined in file [****]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'test-test.spring.Properties': Could not bind properties to 'Properties' : prefix=test, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true
18:56:05.073 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
18:56:05.103 [main] INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
18:56:05.130 [main] ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'test.some-list' to com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList<java.lang.String>:

    Property: test.some-list[0]
    Value: "foo"
    Origin: class path resource [application.yaml] - 6:7
    Reason: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'test.some-list' to com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList<java.lang.String>

Action:

Update your application's configuration


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'someBean' defined in file [****]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'test-test.spring.Properties': Could not bind properties to 'Properties' : prefix=test, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at shared.bootstarters.microservice.SpringMicroservice.startAndInitialize(SpringMicroservice.kt:41)
    at shared.bootstarters.microservice.SpringMicroservice.startAndInitialize$default(SpringMicroservice.kt:30)
    at test.spring.MicroserviceKt.main(Microservice.kt:22)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'test-test.spring.Properties': Could not bind properties to 'Properties' : prefix=test, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConstructorBound.from(ConstructorBound.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.lambda$createBeanDefinition$1(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.java:97)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainInstanceFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.obtainInstanceFromSupplier(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1158)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:888)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'test.some-list' to com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList<java.lang.String>
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.handleBindError(Binder.java:392)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:352)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$4(Binder.java:478)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.ValueObjectBinder$ConstructorParameter.bind(ValueObjectBinder.java:318)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.ValueObjectBinder.bind(ValueObjectBinder.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$5(Binder.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:596)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withDataObject(Binder.java:582)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindDataObject(Binder.java:480)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:419)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:348)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:337)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindOrCreate(Binder.java:329)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindOrCreate(Binder.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.bindOrCreate(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConstructorBound.from(ConstructorBound.java:44)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate Collection type: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList
    at org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createCollection(CollectionFactory.java:212)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.CollectionBinder.lambda$bindAggregate$0(CollectionBinder.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.AggregateBinder$AggregateSupplier.get(AggregateBinder.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.IndexedElementsBinder.bindIndexed(IndexedElementsBinder.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.IndexedElementsBinder.bindIndexed(IndexedElementsBinder.java:86)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.IndexedElementsBinder.bindIndexed(IndexedElementsBinder.java:70)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.CollectionBinder.bindAggregate(CollectionBinder.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.AggregateBinder.bind(AggregateBinder.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindAggregate$3(Binder.java:443)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:596)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindAggregate(Binder.java:443)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:404)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:348)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: null
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createCollection(CollectionFactory.java:208)
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

Comment: We need to see code of the class in question, in addition to  how you’ve added the new converters. And the stack trace. Basically, show, don’t tell.

Comment: Sorry about that! Updated!

Comment: since you’re using Kotlin, you don’t need to do anything additional to make the properties immutable, other than using `val` and immutable collections such as `List`. There are many references to this, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58596161/839733). This [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8762) has more details.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're in a mixed Kotlin/Java environment. So, for example, a Java bean can get the list and call `.add(...)` in it because the Kotlin/Java interface loses the "MutableList vs List" concept and Spring uses mutable lists for instances of `List` on ConfigProps classes.

Comment: Again, such crucial information/requirement should be in the question, and not in the comments extracted by repeated questioning.

Comment: Sorry--I thought what was I was trying to do was clear from the "I want to inject ImmutableList" part of the post. I've updated with an additional clarification.

Comment: Does upgrading to Spring Boot 3.1.5 magically fix things for you?  I see this question referenced in this ticket that was addressed in 3.1.5: [spring-boot#37734](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/37734).

Comment: No, although changing the generics to `<*>` instead of `<Any>` still solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are preventing this from working:

1. There's [a bug in Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/37734) which means that constructor-based binding to a custom `Collection` type does not work.
2. Your custom converter doesn't match due to Kotlin's `Any` being treated as `Object` rather than `?`. I thought that this was a Spring Framework bug. Having opened [#31370](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31370), I now understand that this is how it is with Kotlin and the problem can be avoided by using `<out Any>` rather than `Any` for the `ImmutableList`.

With these problems in mind, binding to Guava's `ImmutableList` can be made to work if you give up on immutability in your `Properties` class:

```kotlin
package com.example.guavaimmutablelist

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner
import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@ComponentScan
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(Properties::class)
class GuavaImmutableListApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<GuavaImmutableListApplication>("--test.someList[0]=zero", "--test.someList[1]=one", "--debug")
}

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
class Properties {
    var someList: ImmutableList<String> = ImmutableList.of()
}

@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
class ListToImmutableListConverter : Converter<List<Any>, ImmutableList<out Any>> {
    override fun convert(source: List<Any>): ImmutableList<out Any> = ImmutableList.copyOf(source)
}

@Component
class SomeBean(
    private val properties: Properties
): CommandLineRunner {
    override fun run(vararg args: String) {
        println("someList: ${properties.someList}")
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh. I expected this one to be "user error", not "Spring bug". Thanks for your help tracking this down as well as the work-around. The assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Cobra1117 The Framework team have pointed out the need to use `<out Any>` rather than `<Any>`. With this approach, you can keep your more loosely-typed converter. I've updated the example to show this approach.

Comment: Interesting... Based on some testing, it looks like `Converter<List<*>, ImmutableList<*>>` works well too. (And that's probably the better choice since it's closer to Java's `Converter<List<?>, ImmutableList<?>>`.) My original `Converter<List<Any>, ImmutableList<Any>>` would be closer to Java's `Converter<List<Object>, ImmutableList<Object>>`, so it's really just bad Kotlin generics on my part. LOL (Either way, thanks for the update!)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is the following corresponding to the [GitHub ticket #34631](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34631). Summarizing:

> The problem lies in `ConversionServiceDeducer`. When the bean factory has a conversion service, any converter beans are added to a second, separate ConversionService. If the first conversion service that comes from the bean factory can perform the requested conversion, the second conversion service isn't used.

I've confirmed this to be the root cause for the custom converter not being invoked.

Apparently, the fix was merged in 3.2.0-M1, but even after using 3.2.0-M3, I'm still able to reproduce the same error.

The hidden underlying exception is that the default converter tries to instantiate a `ImmutableList`, but there's no `public` no-arg constructor, so, the conversion fails.

I also believe that the Kotlin-Java interop is complicating things here, since the source and return types need to match for a converter to be chosen.

I've made a comment in the GitHub ticket asking for advice. Meanwhile, you may debug the `ConversionServiceDeducer` and `Binder` classes source code yourself, I simply am not able to allocate the time needed to go down that rabbit hole and find a specific nugget for you.

I understand this doesn't give you a readymade solution, but I hope it helps to clarify the matter and show you a direction to pursue.

```
package com.example.demo

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesScan
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
data class Properties(
    val someList: ImmutableList<String>
)

@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
class ListToImmutableListConverter : Converter<List<Any>, ImmutableList<Any>> {
    override fun convert(source: List<Any>): ImmutableList<Any> = ImmutableList.copyOf(source)
}

@Component
class SomeBean(
    private val properties: Properties
): CommandLineRunner {
    override fun run(vararg args: String) {
        println("someList: ${properties.someList}")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your help debugging this! Based on Andy Wilkinson's answer, it looks like this is due to a pair of previous undiscovered Spring Framework/Boot bugs.